# How to save binary dat file (.dat) to png or jpg format?

Tags: python, image, binary

I have a binary file format .dat. I want to convert it to png or jpg format, I try to decode it using `numpy.loadtxt()` to get an array list and then save it to png or jpg format. But when I execute it it gives error

> File "C:\Users\SETIKO\Desktop\test\test6-savedattopng.py", line 13, in 
>       arr = np.loadtxt(f)
>     File "C:\Users\SETIKO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1101, in loadtxt
>       for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
>     File "C:\Users\SETIKO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1028, in read_data
>       items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
>     File "C:\Users\SETIKO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1028, in 
>       items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
>     File "C:\Users\SETIKO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 746, in floatconv
>       return float(x)

This is the complete code that I use

```
import numpy as np

f = open('gt.dat', 'rb')
arr = np.loadtxt(f)
```

Is there something missing in my code? or maybe someone has other ideas without having to use `numpy.loadtxt()`?

Here the binary file that I use:
[Binary dat file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11Nq83XSpGtWjAlhmTXzxuBi6ek_bRHRF)

Comment: loadtxt() converts a **text** file to an array (by default of floats). But most probably you have a binary file (while .dat is not a standardized format). And loadtxt() do not find in file any text looking like a number.

Comment: Do you know the dimensions of the image in pixels, I mean is it 5000x3000 pixels? Or what? Do you know if it is colour or greyscale?

Comment: @AlainMerigot do you know the code for looking a number as a binary file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes  the dimension of the image is 5292x744 pixels and it is colour image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its simplest, you can read your file and make it into a PIL/Pillow Image  like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Read file into Numpy array as uint8
na = np.fromfile('GT.dat', dtype=np.uint8)

# Reshape to 5292 px wide, 744 px tall and RGBA, i.e. 4 bytes/per pixel
na = np.reshape(na,(744,5292,4))

# Drop the alpha channel, retaining just RGB
na = na[:,:,:3]

# Convert to PIL/Pillow Image - whilst also brightening because values are all <=5
im = Image.fromarray(na*50,'RGB') 

# Save
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

Or you can not bother writing any code at all and just use **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. So, just in Terminal:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 5292x744 rgba:GT.dat -normalize result.png
```

[image]

---

**Updated Answer**

It seems that all the data is actually in the red channel, and there is nothing in the Green, Blue or Alpha channels. So, we will discard those and then, as the values in the Red channel are all small integers, we will create a palette image where those integers are indices into a palette we can easily manipulate.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Read file into Numpy array as uint8
na = np.fromfile('GT.dat', dtype=np.uint8)

# Reshape to 5292 px wide, 744 px tall and RGBA, i.e. 4 bytes/per pixel
na = np.reshape(na,(744,5292,4))

# Construct a palette
palette = [  
    0, 0, 0,      # 0 - black 
    255, 0, 0,    # 1 - red 
    0, 255, 0,    # 2 - green 
    0, 0, 255     # 3 - blue 
]

# There must be exactly 256 RGB colours, so pad palette to length 768 with zeroes
palette += (768-len(palette))*[0]

# Drop everything except the Red channel which contains all the data
na = na[:,:,0]

# Convert to single channel PIL/Pillow Image
im = Image.fromarray(na,'L') 

# Put our palette into image
im.putpalette(palette)

# Save
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this was so helpful, thank you very much. But I have another question, like you said the values are all <=5, then can I make a condition that if the values are 1 it will contain red color, if 2 it will contain green color, etc? can you please make example code for it?

Comment: I have added code to make a palletised image where the red channel data is used as an index into a colour palette that you can control quite easily. Please have another look.

Comment: can I asked another question? If I reverse the previous question, I have a .png file and want to convert it to .dat as in the gt.dat file, can I use the code ideas above?

Comment: Rather than make a confusing mess of answering 2 questions, it's probably best to ask a new one - questions (and answers) are free anyway. If you do that, click `share` under the new question and copy the link it shows you, then paste a comment with that link on this question so that the two are "joined up". Also, I will get notified if you comment here and will likely be able to reply then.